# Handle exception in extended PDO class

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I'm working with an extended PDO class as follows. But it's `try .. catch` block is not catching the exceptions. Here is the snippet -

```
class ExPDO extends PDO
{
        public function insert(string $sql, array $param){
            try {                   
                $statement = $this->prepare($sql) ;
                $statement->execute($param); //throws exception
            } catch (\PDOException $e) {
               // throw
            }
            catch (\Exception $ex) {
               //throw
            }
        }
 }
```

The exception occurred there, is being handled by the global handler -

```
 set_exception_handler(function($exp){

 });
```

But I would like to handle the exception in `insert()` method.

Any help?

Comment: Why would you handle exceptions in that method in the first place? If the insert throws an exception, it's the code that's calling it that should decide if the exception should be caught (if the app can continue when the insert throws an exception) or if you should leave it be and let your apps main exception handler take care of it. If you really want to do it like this, then please show us how you use the above code and post the full exception you get.

Comment: Did the last catch block catch any exception? If so, what did it catch?

Comment: @shingo Last catch block not catching also.

Comment: So how did you know `execute` method threw an exception?

Comment: @s.k.paul it shoul catch all \Exception, as any exception is inherit from it.. hm... Also \Throwable, try to use that https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php Also see https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php#124604

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto Using "Throwable" is working. Please submit an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have problem with Throwable. You need to use Throwable class since PHP 7. Exception isn't always catch.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php#124604

So It should be

```php
class ExPDO extends PDO
{
        public function insert(string $sql, array $param){
                $statement = $this->prepare($sql) ;
                $statement->execute($param); //throws exception
        }
 }
```

On the other part of the code, you can do

```php
use \ExPDO

$db = new ExPDO();
try {
    $db->insert("Some query;", ["param" => "data"];
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    Log::error($e->getMessage()); // Only Example, try to use monolog or other tools that fits
} catch (\Throwable $t) {
    Log::error($t->getMessage()); // Only Example, try to use monolog or other tools that fits
}
```

as the comments, you should catch it outside the class

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this in library code though.

Comment: For anyone seeing this, never do like the above code; catch an exception just to output it. That will show the exception for every user, no matter if you have `display_errors` set to false (like in production). Not only can exceptions then leak sensitive information, it's also just confusing for users to see some strange exception.

Comment: @M.Eriksson please update the code if you see fit. I just edit it, I don't know whether it's good or not, because it's depend on the one who implement it. He only ask how to catch it, so i put the example.